# Error when launching react native app with emulator

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm trying to launch my react native project for the first time, I have installed everything that is noted on the documentation on react native to use android studio when I run the emulator and I do this command:

```
npx react-native start
```

it's giving me this error in the terminal:

```
error listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::8081.
 Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::8081
at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (net.js:1313:16)
at listenInCluster (net.js:1361:12)
at Server.listen (net.js:1449:7)
at C:\Users\pc\Desktop\AwesomeProject\node_modules\metro\src\index.js:279:18
at new Promise (anonymous)
at Object.anonymous 
(C:\Users\pc\Desktop\AwesomeProject\node_modules\metro\src\index.js:278:12)
at Generator.next (anonymous)
at asyncGeneratorStep 
 (C:\Users\pc\Desktop\AwesomeProject\node_modules\metro\src\index.js:68:24)
at _next (C:\Users\pc\Desktop\AwesomeProject\node_modules\metro\src\index.js:90:9)
 info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you are beginning with react native expo might be a better start: [expo](https://docs.expo.dev/get-started/create-a-new-app/)

Fix: There might be another service using port 8081, if it‘s another node service you can kill it with `taskkill /f /im node.exe`

Answer (score 0):

This happens when some process is already running on the same port which react  is using. We need to kill that process , so our port will be free.

**To kill Process :**

1. netstat -ano | findstr :
2. Now you will get some integer number that is Process ID OR PID: ex: 34573 ,94982.
3. Just copy the PID.
4. taskkill /PID <YOURS_PID> /F

example: taskkill /PID 345872 /F

5. Run app again.